# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, is it true that $\mathbb P (X+Y>x | X+Y>0) \geq \mathbb P (Y>x | Y>0)$ for every $x>0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

$Y$ is a random variable with symmetric distribution around 0 and both random variables are continuous with existing density

It seems true, because the random variable $X$ should just bring further volatility.

---

It basically breaks down to the following: Is it true that

$$\mathbb P (Y \geq 0)\mathbb P (X +Y \geq x) \geq \mathbb P (Y \geq x)\mathbb P (X +Y \geq 0)$$

where $Y$ is symmetric but I do now know how to proceed from here; Oh and for everyone downvoting, you could at least give me a reason to understand why my question is that bad...

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I see that you could improve your answer by adding some contexts, background, reason why you think this is true (or false), etc., so other users can better tune their answers to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false in general.

Here is a counterexample. Let $X$ be uniform over the interval $[-5,-4]$ and $Y$ be uniform over the interval $[-10,10]$. Then $P(X+Y>7|X+Y>0)=0$, but $P(Y>7|Y>0) = 0.3 > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true.  Consider $Y$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|Y| \le x) = 0$.  Then $\mathbb{P}(Y > x | Y > 0) = 1$, but we can easily find an $X$ with $\mathbb{P}(X+Y > x | X+Y > 0) < 1$.